# How to Sync native contacts to my own server?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

How to sync mobile contacts to my own server whenever the contact added, edited or deleted.
please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the contact sync project from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r2.1/com/android/exchange/adapter/ContactsSyncAdapter.java?av=f).This code work fine.

If you want more details refer follow the links,

1.http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/
2.http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

If you want to sync periodically use background services using Timer.